# compilation libjingle pcp

Tags: c++, libjingle

I tried to compile the pcp example in the libjingle project.
But i got this error and i don't know why :

```
g++ -DPOSIX -DEXPAT_RELATIVE_PATH -DFEATURE_ENABLE_SSL -DHAVE_OPENSSL_SSL_H=1  -W -Wall -g -frtti  -o p2p pcp_main.o  -lpthread -lssl libsrtp.a libxmpphelp.a libjingle.a  libexpat.a  
pcp_main.o:(.rodata._ZTI14CustomXmppPump[typeinfo for CustomXmppPump]+0x18): undefined reference to `typeinfo for XmppPump'
pcp_main.o:(.rodata._ZTIN7cricket18SessionManagerTaskE[typeinfo for cricket::SessionManagerTask]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for buzz::XmppTask'
pcp_main.o:(.rodata._ZTIN7cricket15SessionSendTaskE[typeinfo for cricket::SessionSendTask]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for buzz::XmppTask'
pcp_main.o:(.rodata._ZTI17AutoPortAllocator[typeinfo for AutoPortAllocator]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for cricket::HttpPortAllocator'
```

Is anybody know where i made a mistake ???
I spend my all day on it .

Comment: Seems to be linker errors. Usually undefined reference means that you aren't supplying correct library which has the function to which the reference is undefined.

Comment: Yes i know  but normaly all of this are in libxmpphelp.a or libjingle.a . I didn't have other lib to link with . So that's why i didn't understand the typeinfo error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've had the same problem,but did manage to compile it succesfully by scons,  in your talk/ directory append the following line to 'libjingle.scons'

```
     talk.App(env, name = "pcp",
     posix_libs = [
       "crypto",
       "ssl",
     ],
     srcs = [
       "examples/pcp/pcp_main.cc",
     ],
 libs = [
       "jingle",
       "expat",
       "srtp",
       "xmpphelp",
     ],
)
```

And then build it using instructions from the README of libjingle..  pcp binary will be built in your /talk/build/dbg/staging/ directory..