# how to compile pcp fileshare in libjingle

Tags: c++, ftp, p2p, voip, libjingle

okay, i'm trying to compile the fileshare example called 'pcp' using the following command

```
 wolfgang@den-pc:~/tejesh/libjingle-0.6.14/programs$ g++ -g -Wall -DPOSIX
-DEXPAT_RELATIVE_PATH -DFEATURE_ENABLE_SSL -DHAVE_OPENSSL_SSL_H=1  -I ../ pcp_main.cc
 ../talk/build/dbg/lib/libxmpphelp.a ../talk/build/dbg/lib/libjingle.a ../talk/build
 /dbg/lib/libexpat.a ../talk/build/dbg/lib/libsrtp.a -lpthread -lssl
```

And i get the following 'typeinfo' error...

```
 pcp_main.cc: In member function ‘virtual void
 CustomXmppPump::OnStateChange(buzz::XmppEngine::State)’:
 pcp_main.cc:348:12: warning: enumeration value ‘STATE_NONE’ not handled in switch  
 [-Wswitch]
 /tmp/ccVe8JUg.o:(.rodata._ZTI14CustomXmppPump[typeinfo for CustomXmppPump]+0x18): 
 undefined reference to `typeinfo for XmppPump'
 /tmp/ccVe8JUg.o:(.rodata._ZTIN7cricket18SessionManagerTaskE[typeinfo for  
 cricket::SessionManagerTask]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for buzz::XmppTask'
 /tmp/ccVe8JUg.o:(.rodata._ZTIN7cricket15SessionSendTaskE[typeinfo for  
 cricket::SessionSendTask]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for buzz::XmppTask'
 /tmp/ccVe8JUg.o:(.rodata._ZTI17AutoPortAllocator[typeinfo for AutoPortAllocator]+0x8): 
 undefined reference to `typeinfo for cricket::HttpPortAllocator'
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Anybody have some idea on this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [compilation libjingle pcp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105217/compilation-libjingle-pcp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did manage to compile pcp succesfully by scons,......... in your talk/ directory append the following line to 'libjingle.scons'

```
 talk.App(env, name = "pcp",
 posix_libs = [
   "crypto",
   "ssl",
 ],
 srcs = [
   "examples/pcp/pcp_main.cc",
 ],
```

libs = [
       "jingle",
       "expat",
       "srtp",
       "xmpphelp",
     ],
)

And then build it using instructions from the README of libjingle.. pcp binary will be built in your /talk/build/dbg/staging/ directory..

Answer (score 1):

If you compile with gyp, you can change trunk/talk/libjingle_examples.gyp:

```
# target pcp
{
  'target_name': 'pcp',
  'type': 'executable',
  'dependencies': [
    'libjingle_xmpphelp',
    'libjingle.gyp:libjingle',
    'libjingle.gyp:libjingle_p2p',
  ],
  'sources': [
    'examples/pcp/pcp_main.cc',
  ],
},  # target pcp
```

run gclient runhooks again and make.

Comment: After adding pcp manually to `libjingle_examples.gyp` you need to make in this way: `ninja -C out/Debug pcp` on a Linux system. Subsequently you can find the `pcp` binary in `trunk/out/Debug`. The same is true for e.g. `ninja -C out/Debug relayserver`.

Answer (score 0):

This error may be caused by some virtual method not having a definition - i.e. you have declared it but you have not defined its body.

Probably you did not include some .c/.cpp file(s) in the compilation/linking?

Comment: changed all "virtual void function()" to "virtual void function() {} " and all the errors except ... "undefined reference to `typeinfo for XmppPump" are gone... cant find any virtual functions for XmppPump... what else could be the cause of 'typinfo' errors..?